# Accessing host files from Docker without copying and generating output

Tags: python, docker, file, data-binding, dockerfile

I have a Python project with the following directory structure on my host machine:

```
Host Machine:
├── project/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   ├── file2.py
│   │   └── ...
│   └── docs/
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── index.html (Output)
│       └── ...
└── Dockerfile
```

I want to set up a Docker environment for this project where the Python files are located inside the `/src` folder within the Docker machine. However, I do not want to copy the entire `/project` folder into the Docker machine. Additionally, I have specific files (`conf.py`, `index.rst`) and an `index.html` file which serves as the output, in the `/docs` directory on the host machine.

The Docker machine's directory structure should be as follows:

```
Docker Machine:
└── code/
    ├── file1.py
    ├── file2.py
    └── ...
```

Is there a way to utilize bind mounts or any other Docker utility to access the files within the `/src` and `/docs` directories on the host machine directly from the Docker container? I want to execute commands within the Docker environment, such as generating the `index.html` file, but have the output saved on the host machine in the corresponding location.

Specifically, I would like to generate the `index.html` file for the Python files inside the `/code` directory within the Docker container, and have this output file saved on the host machine in the `project/docs/` directory.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this setup using bind mounts or other Docker utilities would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to build an immutable image that's isolated from your host system, do you actually need Docker?  A Python virtual environment can give you an isolated set of packages that won't interfere with other applications, but it runs directly on the host and can directly access host files.  The [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/) page of the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) might be a good starting point.

Comment: I understand what you mean; however, I wanted to use docker since it can automatically set up the environment and exclude the developer dependencies from the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-v` or `--volume` parameter of the `docker run` cli. It allows you to mount local directories and files to your container.

Run the following command from inside your python project directory.

```
# you are inside the project folder

docker run --rm -ti --volume $(pwd)/src:/code --volume $(pwd)/docs:/code/docs --workdir /code --entrypoint bash python:3
```

You can now keep executing your code using the python scripts to generate/update the index.html file in docs folder and because of the volume mounts the changes will be reflected in the correct path on the host machine.

Explanation:

1. `--volume $(pwd)/src:/code` allows you to mount the local dir `src` inside the container's `/code` path
2. `--volume $(pwd)/docs:/code/docs` allows you to mount the local dir `docs` inside the container's `/code/docs` path
3. `--workdir /code` allows you to specify the working directory inside the container. Here in this case I named it as `project` at `/` path.
4. `--entrypoint bash` so that you can access the shell with your mounted filesystem inside the container. This will allow you to run an commands you normally would on your terminal to build/run your python project.
5. `-ti` to get an interactive TTY.
6. `--rm` deletes the container on exit. This is optional.
7. `python:3` This fetches you latest version of python 3. You can choose the python version for your project by replacing 3. Ex. python:3.6 or python:2.7

Comment: @edge selcuk does this answer your question? Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: so do I have to consistently rebuild the container to produce the `index.html` output? I am kind of confused, I know how volumes work but I am not sure how it is supposed to produce index.html only on the host machine

Comment: Updated the docker run command to make sure you dont need to copy the entire project. All you need is 2 volume mounts. You can keep executing the python script from inside the container to generate/update the index.html file in the correct path. You can do so without exiting out of the container or rebuilding it. You can open a second terminal to confirm that the index.html is updating on the host machine on each iteration of your python script.